# Encoding issue in velocity template when the app is deployed in production

Tags: spring, templates, encoding, velocity

I use velocity templates to send emails to my users. These emails have elements such as 's, ñ or ´. When I send emails in local everything works fine and there are no enconding problems.

Nevertheless, If the app is in deployment environment, emails are displayed wrong when using characters like mentioned.

This is my method to send emails:

```
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setFrom(from);
            message.setReplyTo(from);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, templateURI, "UTF-8", model);
            message.setText(body, true);
        }
    };
   try{
       this.mailSender.send(preparator);
   }catch(MailException e){
       logger.error("Mail exception sending the email to "+ to + "\n Exception: " + e.getMessage());


   }
}
```

This is one template example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>[Manager]</title>
    <style>
        body{font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace};
        .message{font-size:0.8em};
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Dear ${user.firstName},</p>
    <p> ${message} </p>
    <p> Best regards, </p>
    <p> Manager <br/>
    Manager system app
    </p>

<p class="message">This message was sent by the admin. Do not answer this email.<br>
If you have any issue, do not hesitate to contact us through the support section in your user panel</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the bean:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>
            resource.loader=class
            contentType=text/html; charset=utf-8
            class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

We use tomcat7 in the production server. Does it need any specific configuration or is a problem in the app config?

Answer (score 0):

There are two other properties you can try to set in the velocity properties:

```
input.encoding = UTF8
output.encoding = UTF8
```